# How to generate secret key using SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong()?

Tags: java, security, random, key

How to generate secret key using SecureRandom.**getInstanceStrong()**?

With this code I can receive byte array with random values. Is there any easy way to generate key of a given length (**256** bits, for example), type (**int, String**) and format (**hex**, bin, dec)?

```
package com.company;

import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class KeyGen {

    public void generate() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {

        SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        byte[] values = new byte[32]; // 256 bit
        random.nextBytes(values);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (byte b : values) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02x", b));
        }
        System.out.print("Key: ");
        System.out.println(sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

`Key: 8fcea84897f48f575c22441ece4e7ddb43ac08cd2c1a83fca46c080768468059`

Comment: You should really have named your package `com.pany` of course :)

Comment: @MaartenBodewes Just a default template in IntelliJ IDEA.

Comment: Ah, OK, using Eclipse by default, didn't know that. For your own cipher there doesn't seem to be much wrong with your current code. You might think about key management though. Maybe putting the random key in some kind of container would be a good idea, or encrypting it with a public PGP key of the teacher (e.g. using Bouncy Castle functionality).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Keys should be of a specific type, e.g. AES. They should preferably be kept inside a `SecretKey` instance or a similar `Key` derived class.

Keys for modern symmetric ciphers consist of bits. Usually you would not need a human/String representation of them (and this could actually harm security). Store them in a `KeyStore` or derive them from a password instead. If you do encode them then the representation format is inconsequential, as long as you don't loose your data during the conversions.

This is probably the best way to generate a strong AES key:

```
public class GenerateStrongAESKey {

    public static SecretKey generateStrongAESKey(final int keysize) {
        final KeyGenerator kgen;
        try {
            kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("AES key generator should always be available in a Java runtime", e);
        }
        final SecureRandom rng;
        try {
            rng = SecureRandom.getInstanceStrong();
        } catch (final NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException("No strong secure random available to generate strong AES key", e);
        }
        // already throws IllegalParameterException for wrong key sizes
        kgen.init(keysize, rng);

        return kgen.generateKey();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SecretKey strongAESKey = generateStrongAESKey(256);
        // well, if you must have a human readable string, here it is
        // but you've been warned
        System.out.println(toHex(strongAESKey.getEncoded()));
    }

    private static String toHex(final byte[] data) {
        final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(data.length * 2);
        for (byte b : data) {
            sb.append(String.format("%02X", b));
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Note: this requires the unlimited strength jurisdictional files for the Oracle runtime environment for keys > 128 bits.

Comment: I need `human readable string` for my GOST/Magma block cipher realization. In my case I need to show encryption key to the teacher. Or to save him somehow.

Comment: But I don't fully understand what are fundamental differences between your code and mine, if we get same (?) result.

Comment: The differences are that your code simply uses a byte array, while mine uses the JCE. The output values may be the same (or at least, the same kind of random), but the above code may for instance protect the keys or use hardware devices when available. Of course, that's not very helpful if you want to generate a key for a self made cipher. In that case there is little wrong with your code. As said, Java fortunately doesn't output hexadecimals or other human readable strings as an (insecure) default.